# How many MySQL database can be created in a single domain in Plesk control panel?

Tags: mysql, plesk

Do you have any experience about this question? I have currently 1900 MySQL databases in a single domain in my plesk control panel and I wonder if my MySQL server gets overloaded or out-of-service due to such high number of databases in the system.

Do you have any suggestions? Each database is for a user in my service by the way.

Comment: It'd probably be better to have one database and have records have a user_id field.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Plesk is control panel for administering a shared hosting setup.  We're dealing with different users each having one or more websites and each site potentially having multiple DBs associated with it (IE - joe's running wordpress & a forum, jane's running her own wordpress and a custom e-commerce app).

Comment: In response to your comment on my answer: The filesystem limits will depend which filesystem is on that particular drive. For example, I read some anecdotal data that an NTFS drive started to have a lot of trouble after 30,000-some databases were created, but I have no idea how that compares to other file systems. As for ways to fix this up, I probably wouldn't worry too much about it yet, if 30,000 is a "typical" limit, you're not even 10% of the way there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL itself doesn't place any restrictions on the number of databases you can have, and I doubt Plesk does either, I'm sure it just displays all the databases present on the MySQL server.

However, your host may have a limit (which you'd have to ask them about), or if you start getting a **huge** number of databases, you may actually run into a filesystem limit. As [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-database.html) says, each database is stored as a directory, so you could hypothetically hit the filesystem's upper limit for how many subdirectories are allowed.

Comment: Hi Chad, sounds correct. Do you know the filesystem limit on Redhat Enterprise Linux 5?

So, the solution is one of the following then:

1. Merging databases: Each user database tables will be prefixed with a special user code (or ID). I believe this will have a filesystem limit as well.

2. Getting another MySQL server on the same network.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

ive got well over 5000 databases running on alinux based plesk cluster (one db one web server) and its running fine, though i have had to increase open files limits due to the huge amounts of files. i cant run the mysql tuning primer any more though, well i can but it takes about 4 hours

Comment: Hi DJ_Steve,

Glad to hear that there is someone else who is following the same way like me :)

Steve, could you please tell me how did you enable "open files limit". Sorry if this is a stupid question.